# Why doesn't my click event handler on a "<option>" run in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-select

Why doesn't this JS work in IE? Opera, FF, Chrome are working correctly, but it does nothing in IE.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var zaloha = new Array();
function filtrovanie(objekt){
    var zoznam = document.getElementById("filtruj");
    var pocet = 0;
    if(zaloha!="")
        for(i=0;i<zaloha.length;i++)
            zoznam.appendChild(zaloha[i]);
    for(i=0;i<zoznam.length;i++){
        moznost=zoznam.getElementsByTagName("option")[i];
        if(moznost.getAttribute("title").toUpperCase() != objekt.getAttribute("name").toUpperCase()){
            zaloha[pocet]=moznost;
            pocet++;
            zoznam.removeChild(moznost);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select name="options_id" size="5">
<option onClick="filtrovanie(this)"  name="Farba" value="1">Farba&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[Radio]/option>
<option onClick="filtrovanie(this)"  name="Pohlavie" value="5">Pohlavie&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Radio]</option>
<option onClick="filtrovanie(this)"  name="Vek" value="4">Vek&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[Dropdown]/option>
<option onClick="filtrovanie(this)"  name="Veľkosť" value="2">Veľkosť&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dropdown]</option>
</select>

<select id="filtruj" multiple="multiple" name="values_id[]" size="5">
<option title="FARBA" name="Biela" value="30">Biela&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[FARBA]</option>
<option title="FARBA" name="Fialová" value="27">Fialová&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[FARBA]</option>
<option title="FARBA" name="Oranžová" value="88">Oranžová&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[FARBA]</option>
<option title="FARBA" name="šedá" value="101">šedá&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[FARBA]</option>
<option title="FARBA" name="Červená" value="16">Červená&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[FARBA]</option>
<option title="FARBA" name="Čierna" value="29">Čierna&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[FARBA]</option>
<option title="POHLAVIE" name="Chlapec" value="97">Chlapec&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[POHLAVIE]</option>
<option title="POHLAVIE" name="Dievča" value="98">Dievča&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[POHLAVIE]</option>
<option title="RESERVED FOR TEXT/FILES ONLY ATTRIBUTES" name="TEXT" value="0">TEXT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[RESERVED FOR TEXT/FILES ONLY ATTRIBUTES]</option>
<option title="VEK" name="0 - 2 roky" value="77">0 - 2 roky&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[VEK]</option>
<option title="VEK" name="2 - 4 roky" value="96">2 - 4 roky&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[VEK]</option>
<option title="VEľKOSť" name="104" value="76">104&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[VEľKOSť]</option>
<option title="VEľKOSť" name="110" value="100">110&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[VEľKOSť]</option>
<option title="VEľKOSť" name="116" value="103">116&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[VEľKOSť]</option>
<option title="VEľKOSť" name="122" value="105">122&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[VEľKOSť]</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support the click event on option elements. You can try the select element's change event, but test keyboard navigation carefully in IE as it dispatches a change event each time the cursor key is pressed to select the next or previous option.